# Angularjs - How to apply different class in <tr> conditionally to repeat directive

Tags: indexing, angularjs, repeat

I need to apply a different class to a `<tr>` according to the `$index` of the repeat directive. For example

```
<table>
   <tr ng-repeat="model in list" class="xxx">
       <td>...</td>
   <tr>
</table>
```

I need to apply a different style to `<tr>` depending on whether the index is even and odd.

How could I solve this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Normally you would use ngClassOdd ([http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngClassOdd](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angClassOdd)) and ngClassEven ([http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngClassEven](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angClassEven)) directives like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in items" ng-class-odd="'class1'" ng-class-even="'class2'">
```

Here is the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pkozlowski_opensource/hNHJ4/1/

Unfortunately there is an issue where the mentioned directives are not working correctly when rows are removed: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1076

As a work around you can use the ngClass directive ([http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngClass](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angClass)) with the $index variable exposed by a repeater:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in items" ng-class="{class1 : $index%2==0, class2 : !($index%2==0)}">
```

Here is the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pkozlowski_opensource/am7xs/

It is not super-clean, but could be improved (for example, by exposing a function in a root scope, something like:

```
ng-class="getClass($index,'class1','class2')"
```

till the mentioned bug is fixed

Comment: I wonder if its possible to append a TR that goes outside the grain of the other TR's.. preferably one with a title header. Like every row is a week, and then a TR is a header for that month or that year but doesn't contain 7 TD's.. I'm getting that this is impossible to do with Angular..

Comment: I would put the "bug is fixed" line before explaining how to work around, emphasized.

Answer (score 5):

If this is just for styling you can just use CSS

```
tr:nth-child(odd) { ... }
tr:nth-child(even) {...}
```

see http://jsfiddle.net/5MSDC/ for an example

Comment: Actually this is the correct way of doing it. Since it's a CSS class thing, CSS is the best way to do it.

Comment: The Who, you've got a typo: tr:nth-child(event) {...} .. it should be even not event.